# Mockito never() get called even when the method is not called?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

Here's my Repo

```
interface TrendingRepository{

fun getTrendingRepos()
```

Test Class

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class TrendingViewModelTest {

    private val trendingRepository = mock(TrendingRepository::class.java)
    private var trendingViewModel = TrendingViewModel(trendingRepository)

    @Test
    fun testWithNoNetwork() {
        trendingViewModel.isConnected = false
        verify(trendingRepository, never()).getTrendingRepos()
    }

    @Test
    fun testWithNetwork() {
        trendingViewModel.isConnected = true
        verify(trendingRepository, never()).getTrendingRepos()
    }
}
```

TrendingViewModel

```
fun fetchTrendingRepos() {
    if (isConnected) {
        loadingProgress.value = true
        compositeDisposable.add(
            trendingRepository.getTrendingRepos().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ response ->
                    run {
                        loadingProgress.value = false
                },
                    { error ->
                        loadingProgress.value = false
                    }
                )
        )
    }
```

Both these test are passing, however `TrendingViewModel` is only calling `getTrendingRepos()` only when there is active network, `isConnected = true`

Comment: Can you put code of TrendingViewModel?

Comment: Added that too. @NatigBabayev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call function that you're testing before verification:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class TrendingViewModelTest {

    private val trendingRepository = mock(TrendingRepository::class.java)
    private var trendingViewModel = TrendingViewModel(trendingRepository)

    @Test
    fun testWithNoNetwork() {
        trendingViewModel.isConnected = false
        trendingViewModel.fetchTrendingRepos()
        verify(trendingRepository, never()).getTrendingRepos()
    }

    @Test
    fun testWithNetwork() {
        trendingViewModel.isConnected = true
        trendingViewModel.fetchTrendingRepos()
        verify(trendingRepository, times(1)).getTrendingRepos()
    }
}
```

Comment: if `isConnected = true` fetchTrendingRepos() should be called right, but in the method `testWithNetwork` you're checking it with never(). Is that right. (I'm a newbie to tesing) @Natig Babayev

Comment: Yes, I updated code. If isConnected = true, `verify(trendingRepository, times(1)).getTrendingRepos()`

Comment: In which line error happens? Did you use updated code?

Comment: that compositedisposable is null, which is causing that issue, how can i rid of that @Natig Babayev

Comment: In TrendingViewModel, you should initialize compositeDisposable: private compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

Comment: I got it. You were so helpful , thankyou bro :) @Natig Babayev

Comment: I'm happy to be helpful! :)